# Simple math in HTML enter three values and get result after last value entered

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fiddle going over here:
[jsfiddle.net/vuYMs/172](http://jsfiddle.net/vuYMs/172)

```
<table border="3" width="600" style="background-color:#FFAAAA;border-collapse:collapse;border:3px solid #550000;color:#550000" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
    <td  colspan="4" align="center">Time Calculation</td>       
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Start Time</td>
    <td>Break Duration</td>
    <td>Work Duration</td>
    <td>Leave Time</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="Start1"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="Break1"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="Work1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Leave1"/></td>
</tr>
```

```
var St1 = document.getElementsByName("Start1")[0];
var Br1 = document.getElementsByName("Break1")[0];
var Wo1 = document.getElementsByName("Work1")[0];
var Le1 = document.getElementsByName("Leave1")[0];

function changeInput(e){     
    var calc = St1+Br1+Wo1
    Le1.value = calc;
}

Wo1.onchange = changeInput;
```

I'm trying something very basic but I can't seem to get it to work.
Objective: Enter three values and have a result appear after last value entered.

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: That fiddle is a totally different code. What's Le1 in your javascript code?

Comment: Apart from the fact that there's a semicolon missing after "var calc = St1+Br1+Wo1" I don't see anything wrong. What's the result you're getting?

Comment: @nitram, There are so many things wrong with this code.

Comment: St1 is the textbook. If you want to get the value inside it, you need to use `St1.value`. But, that will give you a string. Besides that, start time is not a number. You need to use a datetime for that.

Comment: OK, I guess I should have spent a little more time looking at it... ;-)

Comment: Sorry first time messing around in here. Give me one moment and I'll update. Sorry for the confusion. I'll make the change by @nitram and ataravati and put it back in.

Comment: @ataravati Sorry about the mess, I'll fix.

Comment: Hi, I never "updated" the fiddle, sorry about that. New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuYMs/172/ I'm happy at this point of learning to only use "number" so I've changed the St1 to number, and added to semicolon. I also added in Le1, but I'm not sure if I've declared it correctly or not.

Comment: @user3224491, update the link to the fiddle in your code, and add Le1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

St1, Br1, and Wo1 are references to the textbooks. If you want to add the values inside those textboxes, you should do it like this:

```
function changeInput(){     
   var calc = parseInt(St1.value) + parseInt(Br1.value) + parseInt(Wo1.value);

   Le1.value = calc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry about the original mess!  This works perfect! http://jsfiddle.net/vuYMs/173/